# Hover zoom for div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with JQuery Booklet from http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/.
But there is no Zoom option. I've tried different plugins for zoom and came across only hover zoom for images.
I want to hover zoom as shown in the below link:
http://issuu.com/burstmagazine/docs/burst_magazine_issue9_september2013

Is there a free Jquery plugin for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Zoomooz plugins](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/) they are free and simple to use

See [Simple Zoom Demo with Zoomooz on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mVf8Z/48/)

```
$("#zoom").hover(function () {
    $(this).zoomTo({
        targetsize: 1.0,
        root: $(".container")
    });
});
```

Comment: can't get want u want to say

Comment: the detail explanation is given on the site with examples

Comment: zomooz is not good. I want the plugin like this:http://issuu.com/burstmagazine/docs/burst_magazine_issue9_september2013

Comment: @Pearl that was guidline...And u wake up so early

Comment: sTACKoVERFLOW:Thanks. Is there any exact Jquery plugin like that.